# Using different version of MSBUILD.exe between Dev and Jenkins machine

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild

I have a C# project developed with VS2017.

The *server* on which Jenkins runs doesn't have VS installed. I have .NET 4.7 installed on the *dev* computer and the *server*.

This is what I get when I type msbuild.exe /version:

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version XXX(see below)

- On dev, I have 2 MSBUILD.exe:

  - C:...\MicrosoftVisualStudio\2017\Pro\MSBuild\15.0\Bin: 15.1.1012.6693
  - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319: 4.7.2053.0
- On server: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319: 4.7.2053.0

I assume that when I build a project in VS2017, it uses the MSBUILD.exe located in the MicrosoftVisualStudio folder.

I'm concerned now to build on the Jenkins machine with a different version of MSBUILD.exe? What would be the best approach? Copy the folder *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild* to the Jenkins computer?

Comment: Either you use Visual Studio folder MsBuild.exe or .Net framework MsBuild it doesn't matter as long as the resolving dependencies available.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what MSBuild features you use.

The safe way to build projects developed in VS 2017 is to build using the installed VS version of MSBuild (15) from either a full VS installation or the [`Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017`](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

Even though the .NET Framework version of MSBulid will be able to build a lot of projects, it is limited to an older C# version, so you'd have to install the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` NuGet package to replace the compiler. But VS 2017 introduces new MSBuild syntax features as well as build tasks which cannot be patched into the legacy version of MSBuild so its use is highly discouraged.

Comment: Thank you. So what do you recommend? Does it work if I just copy the msbuild folder from VS2017 or I should install VS2017? I cannot use the community release and I don't want to buy a second VS Pro license just for jenkins.

Comment: I suggest the build tools, they are meant to be used in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting several errors using on the server this version of MSBUILD.exe: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319: 4.7.2053.0

Here are the steps followed to builwithout error a VS2017 C# on Jenkins 2.60.2

1. Copy C:...\MicrosoftVisualStudio\2017\Pro\MSBuild to my server
2. In Jenkins/Global Tool Configuration, in the MSBUILD section

   - Name: msbuild.exe
   - Path to MSBuild: C:\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
   - Default parameters: -p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7"

If Default parameters is empty, I was getting errors, so it is important.